# UILabels not rendering in UIStackView with addArrangedView; render with addSubView

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uistackview

I have a UIStackView and I am trying to add 2 labels as children. When I add them using addArrangedSubview nothing renders inside of my View, but when I just use addSubview both labels render (albeit not where I want them). What am I doing wrong?

```
import UIKit

class RepCounterView : UIView {
    var count : Int = 0

    lazy var repCountLabel: UILabel = {
        let repCountLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 120, height: 120))
        repCountLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
        repCountLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 100)
        repCountLabel.text = String(count)
        repCountLabel.textAlignment = .center

        return repCountLabel
    }()

    lazy var repsLabel: UILabel = {
        let repsLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 120, height: 120))
        repsLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
        repsLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10)
        repsLabel.text = repCountLabel.text == "1" ? "rep" : "reps"
        return repsLabel
    }()

    lazy var stackView : UIStackView = {
        let stackView = UIStackView()
        stackView.axis = .horizontal
        stackView.distribution = .fill
        stackView.alignment = .center

        return stackView
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.setup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.setup()
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.bounds.size.width / 2
    }

    func setup() {
        self.clipsToBounds = true
        self.addSubview(self.stackView)

        // This is where .addSubview works, but this doesn't
        self.stackView.addArrangedSubview(repCountLabel)
        self.stackView.addArrangedSubview(repsLabel)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import UIKit

class RepCounterView : UIView {
var count : Int = 5

lazy var repCountLabel: UILabel = {
    let repCountLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 120, height: 120))
    repCountLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
    repCountLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 100)
    repCountLabel.text = String(count)
    repCountLabel.textAlignment = .center

    return repCountLabel
}()

lazy var repsLabel: UILabel = {
    let repsLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 120, height: 120))
    repsLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
    repsLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10)
    repsLabel.text = repCountLabel.text == "1" ? "rep" : "reps"
    return repsLabel
}()

lazy var stackView : UIStackView = {
    let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [repCountLabel, repsLabel])
    stackView.axis = .horizontal
    stackView.distribution = .fill
    stackView.alignment = .center
    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return stackView
}()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.setup()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self.setup()
}

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    self.layer.cornerRadius = self.bounds.size.width / 2
}

func setup() {
    self.clipsToBounds = true
    self.addSubview(self.stackView)
    stackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
    stackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true

    // This is where .addSubview works, but this doesn't
    //        self.stackView.addArrangedSubview(repCountLabel)
    //        self.stackView.addArrangedSubview(repsLabel)
    }
    }
```

Try this updated code of yours.
[image]

Comment: Sadly this didn't work. I have tried setting stackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true, and for height as well. No progress

Comment: You have to add `stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` then constraint has effect otherwise not

Comment: yes you should add `stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` if you give height and width anchor. I tried your code working for me and it should work for you also.

Answer (score 1):

If you are giving constraints using auto layout, you have to add `tackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`. Your updated code,

```
lazy var stackView : UIStackView = {
        let stackView = UIStackView()
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stackView.axis = .horizontal
        stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
        stackView.alignment = .fill

        return stackView
    }()

func setup() {
        self.clipsToBounds = true
        self.addSubview(self.stackView)

        // This is where .addSubview works, but this doesn't
        self.stackView.addArrangedSubview(repCountLabel)
        self.stackView.addArrangedSubview(repsLabel)

        stackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
        stackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true 
    }
```